# What does @interface mean in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, class

I am learning Obj-C and don't quite understand the purpose of the code on lines 3 to 5.

Can someone please explain them?

```
1.  myClassA.m
2.  #import myClassB
3.  @interface myClassA()
4.  -(void) methodA   
5.  @end
6.  @implementation myClassA
7.  mymethodA {
        NSLog{@"this is mymethodA");
    }
```

If you have some references about these, I am happy to go over it by myself.

Comment: Basically, @interface construction is a declaration of what your class can do, visible to other classes, so other classes can call on methods and access properties of this class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [@interface and @protocol explanation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679145/interface-and-protocol-explanation)

Comment: -1 Code contains syntax errors. Then, asking about `@interface` in this way is confusing and yielded confusing answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to Josh's answer, Stanford's Paul Hegarty, lecturing on iPad and iPhone programming stated it simply as (paraphrasing here):

> Stuff defined (methods or properties) in the .h header file is public, stuff defined with @interface in the .m implementation file is private.

Hegarty's lecture is very current and freely available on iTunes University.

Comment: I went thru his lecture but did not remember exactly which lecture is covered this topic. Can you tell me which lecture it is ?

Answer (score 0):

As Josh said, the class interface declares the methods your class will contain. You can think of the methods inside as "private" in the sense that they cannot be seen by other files, even if they include myClass.h.

To be clear, the method declarations you choose to put in myClass.h will be accessible to any other file that includes myClass.h. The method declarations you choose to put in your class interface will only be accessible by myClass.m.

Generally it is considered good practice to hide as much as possible, so it is recommended to put methods that are private to myClass.m within the class interface.

Comment: -1: You are explaining Objective-C's *class extension* feature but do not mention it's name. Instead you refer to it using "class interface" which is confusing.

Answer (score -1):

Line 3 marks the beginning of a class interface. This declares the methods your class will contain, but doesn't describe their functionality. Line 4 can actually extend to line N, depending on how many methods you have in your class.

Then, between lines 6 and 8 (@end), you will place the definitions for the actual behavior of those methods. That way, users can import your header, as you're doing with myClassB, and get a full list of functions that your class exposes.

Answer (score -1):

Lines 3-5 are specifying the interface to the class (kind of like a header file in C++).  The - at the start of line 4 means the method is an instance (as opposed to class) method.

Comment: -1: Lines 3 declares a class extension, not the classes interface. It's usually part of the implementation file, not the header.